# How to debug WebRTC/ORTC events in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: debugging, webrtc, microsoft-edge, ortc

Is there a way to debug what RTC events are send from and to MS Edge? We use [webrtc adapter](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) and it works great on Chrome and FF but Edge is breaking for some reason. I would need to debug what Edge is doing when we want to setup a connection and i.e. does it receive the `setRemoteDescription` event or not etc.

Are there any debug tools our there? I was thinking of a network sniffer like WireShark but not sure if that'll work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Philip hancke is hard at work finishing the WEBRTC-on-ORTC shim in adapter.js right now. While it's getting better, I'm not sure it's all there yet. Moreover, the ORTC implementation in Edge is also not "complete", especially for video codecs.

If you still want to go down this path before it's stabilised, you should open tickets and ask in the github's adapter.js repository. They are usually pretty fast at answering.